# how to use div to layout page

Tags: javascript, html

I am using div to layout a page. The page has two columns. The first column is a map. The second column contains three rows of graphs. I used the code below. The result gives me just one column (instead of two) with four rows. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!-- This is where the map will live -->    
<div id="map-container" style="width:1000px; height:500px"></div>

<!-- CHARTS!!! -->

<div class="row">

    <!-- row chart -->
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <div id="rowchart2" class="dc-chart"></div>
        <center><div class="title">Severity</div></center>
    </div>

    <!-- Histogram-->
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
        <div id="rowchart" class="dc-chart"></div>
        <center><div class="title">Histogram(Delta Speed)</div></center>
    </div>

    <!-- row chart -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0">
        <div id="rowchart3" class="dc-chart"></div>
        <center><div class="title">Direction</div></center>     
    </div>                  
</div>
```

Comment: Where is you css code. Please show us, or better, create a jsfiddle.

Comment: Your code does not do anything to set up columns. The `class` attributes as such have no effect. You are probably using some library or framework. Please mention it and tag the question with it.

Comment: Have you included bootstrap lib, from html code it seems you are using it?

Comment: read Bootstrap's grid system properly.Your grid structure is completely wrong.

Comment: The code does not contain any JavaScript. You should either show the relevant JavaScript code or remove the “javascript” tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Column 1:


            <div id="map-container" class="col-md-12" style="width:100%; height:500px"></div>


        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">


            OTHER DATA HERE

        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Bootstrap here, you need to layout your two columns within a single row so that they will sit side by side. For example, if you want to have two columns that are equal widths, you could use:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- Map Here -->
    </div>
    <div class=col-md-6">
        <div>Chart 1</div>
        <div>Chart 2</div>
        <div>Chart 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are always 12 columns in a row, so using "col-md-6" for each column results in two equally sized columns.

Within the second column, you could nest more rows and columns to give you more control:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <!-- Map Here -->
    </div>
    <div class=col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">Big Chart 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">Small Chart 2</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">Small Chart 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For an example layout, here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q3vdex96/2/

In your example, you're setting the map to have a width of 1000px. You shouldn't set an explicit width in this way - let Bootstrap handle the sizing using its grid system. Bootstrap's responsive CSS means your charts and map will collapse into a single column on a small screen, and will automatically expand into the correct layout as the screen size increases.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing your CSS so part of what I say is just a wild guess.

First, the center element is obsolete. Don't use that.

Second, div elements are block level and will extend the entire width of the page by default. This is why you only get one column but, as I said, without a link or a jsfiddle with the complete markup, it's all a guess.